# How to Parse Repeated Name-Value Pairs using Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to parse key/value token strings out of text using Regex in C#.  For example, given the string:

```
stuff{token1:param1}stuff{token2}stuff{token3:param3}stuff
```

I would end out with three capture groups:

```
(key=token1,value=param1)
(key=token2,value=(null))
(key=token3,value=param3)
```

My problem isn't writing a regular expression to do the parsing, my problem is grouping together the keys and values.

Here's the code I have so far.  ("tokenPattern" is split out just to make the regular expression a bit less overwhelming.)

```
var text = "{token1:param1}stuff{token2}more stuff{token3:param3}";
var tokenPattern = @"(?<token>[{](?<key>[^:}]*)([:](?<value>[^}]*))?[}])";
var pattern = @"([^{]*" + tokenPattern + ")*.*?";
var match = Regex.Match(text, pattern);
```

The match is successful, and the the resulting Groups of interest in the "match" variable are:

```
? match.Groups["token"].Captures
Count = 3
    [0]: {{token1:param1}}
    [1]: {{token2}}
    [2]: {{token3:param3}}
? match.Groups["key"].Captures
Count = 3
    [0]: {token1}
    [1]: {token2}
    [2]: {token3}
? match.Groups["value"].Captures
Count = 2
    [0]: {param1}
    [1]: {param3}
```

Because the "value" portion of my tokens are optional, I can't find a way to match up "key"s with "value"s.  I could, I suppose, re-parse each the "token" captures but that seems a bit of a pain.

Is there a way to drill into a "token" capture to find the associated "key" and "value" (if any) for that specific capture?

Comment: Why do you use character classes (`[]`) with single characters in them in your regular expression? That is just the same as the character?

Comment: @NetMage.  Mostly cause I was being lazy; I knew {, }, and : have special meanings in some contexts in RegEx and I wanted to rule out accidents.  Wiktor has cleaned this up for me below.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simpler pattern to match all pattern occurrences in the string using `Regex.Matches` - all the necessary strings will already be grouped:

```cs
var text = "{token1:param1}stuff{token2}more stuff{token3:param3}";
var pattern = @"\{(?<key>[^:}]*)(?::(?<value>[^}]*))?}";
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["key"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["value"].Value);
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/spQKCz) and the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%7B%28%3F%3Ckey%3E%5B%5E%3A%7D%5D*%29%28%3F%3A%3A%28%3F%3Cvalue%3E%5B%5E%7D%5D*%29%29%3F%7D&i=stuff%7Btoken1%3Aparam1%7Dstuff%7Btoken2%7Dstuff%7Btoken3%3Aparam3%7Dstuff). `\{(?<key>[^:}]*)(?::(?<value>[^}]*))?}` matches

- `\{` - a `{` char
- `(?<key>[^:}]*)` - Group "key": zero or more chars other than `:` and `}`
- `(?::(?<value>[^}]*))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching `:` and then Group "value" matching zero or more chars other than `}`
- `}` - a `}` char.